# Using Tweepy and Twitter API v2 to retrieve replies from a single Tweet

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, paginator

I'm currently trying to generate the replies for a single tweet, but can't retrieve all of them. While it works to retrieve some, adding .flatten(limit=1000) breaks my code and will return an error.

I need to return all replies from a single tweet and am using paginator to do so, but for some reason am only seeing 6 replies of the multiple hundred.

```
import csv
from multiprocessing.connection import Client
import tweepy
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

# Oauth and client creation
bearer_token = "XXX"
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token)

# update these for the tweet you want to process replies to 'name' = the account username and you can find the tweet id within the tweet URL
#name = 'XXX'
#tweet_id = 'XXX'
q = 'conversation_id:XXX'

for tweet_batch in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets, query=q,
                                    tweet_fields=['context_annotations','created_at', 'public_metrics', 'author_id'], 
                                    user_fields=['name','username','location','verified','description'],
                                    max_results=100, expansions='author_id'):
                                        tweets = tweet_batch.data
                                        users = tweet_batch.includes["users"]

users = {user["id"]: user for user in users}
print(len(tweets),len(users))
with open('replies_clean.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=('user', 'text'))
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    for tweet in tweets:
        user = users[tweet.author_id]
        row = {'user': '@' + user.username, 'text': tweet.text.replace('\n', ' ')}
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Could this be date-related? The recent search function will only find Tweets posted in the last 7 days.

Comment: @AndyPiper the tweet I was using was actually only 3 days ago so I don’t think so, but I definitely should’ve specified that

Answer (score 1):

It's a small issue with your code. In the for loop you are overwriting the `tweets` and `users` lists with each pass instead of appending to it. Corrected loop:

```
q = 'conversation_id:XXX'
tweets = []
users = []

for tweet_batch in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets, query=q,
                                    tweet_fields=['context_annotations','created_at', 'public_metrics', 'author_id'],
                                    user_fields=['name','username','location','verified','description'],
                                    max_results=100, expansions='author_id'):

                                        for tweet in tweet_batch.data:
                                            tweets.append(tweet)
                                        for user in tweet_batch.includes["users"]:
                                            users.append(user)
```